# laravel timezone formate setting

Tags: laravel, timezone, laravel-blade

I want to show the time and timezone in the blade file

```
<div class='rightNavTag'>
    {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($current_time)->setTimezone(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->timezone ?? config('app.timezone'))->format('H:i:s \(\G\M\TP\)') }}
</div>
```

$current_time is timestamp sended from server.

It now shows 14:54:26 (GMT +08:00)

Anyone knows how to set it to 14:54:26 (GMT+8) ?

Comment: You need to do your custom format because don't [exist](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats), please and add to the end `. ' (GMT' . (\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($current_time)->offsetHours >= 0 ? '+' : '') .
            \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($current_time)->offsetHours . ')'` to change the last part.